# Language and lyrics for Massano's "Indianotech"

Tags: lyrics

I'm looking for lyrics to the song "[Indianotech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFYDcpWYULk)" by Mossano.

I'd like the language it is sung in, the text of the original lyrics, and if possible, an English translation.  I've tried searching online, but without success.

Comment: This is the right place to ask, it looks like.

Comment: Do you mean you're looking for the **lyrics**  ?

Comment: Massano appears to be an award-winning Romanian DJ, but I'm almost certain the song he is remixing is Bollywood, which would make likely be be sung in Hindi.  This is largely speculation, which is why I'm not making it an official answer.